# How to create FileChooser using JavaFx/Gluon that works on Android and IOS

Tags: android, ios, javafx, gluon, gluon-mobile

I am trying to choose a file to upload in my Gluon application. The filechooser Javafx code works on Desktop but not on Android.

I have seen posts that the JavaFx file chooser is not compatible in Android.

How do I implement a filechooser that is compatible on all platforms?

Answer (score 0):

It is true, JavaFX file chooser is not compatible with mobile platforms. But you can use a combination of platform-independent Charm-Down Apis (to access your local storage) and your custom JavaFX code to develop one.
Here are CharmDown [docs](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/4.4.1/#_charm_down) and [samples](http://gluonhq.com/developers/samples/#mobile) which should be helpful.